# Search int Array with Binary Search Java

Tags: java, arrays, search, binary-search

I have an int array that I need to perform a binary search on. If the user-inputted number is found in the array, the index at which it is located should be returned. This index corresponds to an index in another array which is then outputted. The problem is that for the first search, the only input number that provides a result is 1. If I do more than one search my program fails and no results are displayed. I can't see why my search isn't working, can someone provide some input as to what I am doing wrong?

```
public class childrensclassics extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 int[] refInts;
```

...

```
private void searchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    //declare variables
    int refNumBinary = Integer.parseInt(refInput.getText());
    String refNum = refInput.getText();
    int binary;

    //binary search
    binary = binarySearch(refInts, 0, refInts.length-1, refNumBinary);

    //check binary search results
    if (binary == -1){
        errorLabel.setText("Data not found. Please Try again.");
    }
    else {
        binaryOutput.setText("#" + refNum + ": " + titlesArray[binary]);
    }

public static Integer binarySearch(int [] A, int left, int right, int V){
     if (left > right) {
         return -1;
     }
     int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
     if (V == A[middle]) {
         return middle;
     }
     if (V < A[middle]) {
         return binarySearch(A, left, middle-1, V);
     } else {
         return binarySearch(A, middle + 1, right, V);
     }
 }
```

**EDIT**:

> Sample of Data Contained in refInts Array:

1,
2,
4,
6,
10,
12,
14,
20,
24,
26,

> Sample of Data Contained in titlesArray:

The Adventures of Tom Sawyer,
Huckleberry Finn,
The Sword in the Stone,
Stuart Little,
Treasure Island,
The Secret Garden,
Alice's Adventures in Wonderland,
Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea,
Peter Pan,
Charlotte's Web,

This is my adding process if it helps, the data is coming from a text file of mixed reference numbers and titles, all of which are on their own line. In my initial code I take the data from the text file and put it all in one array called bookList. For binary searching purposes I'm pretty sure I need to separate the two different data types. It's a roundabout way but I'm relatively new to java and couldn't think of a different way.

> Format of Data in Original Array

```
1
The Adventures of Tom Sawyer
2
Huckleberry Finn
3
The Sword in the Stone
...
```

**ADDING PROCESS:**

Take the even index numbers which hold reference numbers and the odd index numbers which hold the titles and separate them.

```
//separate data for binary search
for (int i = 0; i < bookList.length; i++) {
     if (i%2==0) {
         refNums.add(bookList[i]);
     } else{
         titles.add(bookList[i]);
     }
} 

//create searchable arrays
titlesArray = new String[(bookList.length)/2];
titles.toArray(titlesArray);

refsArray = new String[(bookList.length)/2];
refNums.toArray(refsArray);

//create int array
int[] refInts = new int[refsArray.length];

//send reference number to int array
for (int i = 0; i < refsArray.length; i++) {
    refInts[i] = Integer.parseInt(refsArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: perhaps include some sample data you're working with.

Comment: How about using the existing implementation (java.util.Arrays.binarySearch)?

Comment: Hint: add trace prints to your code; or learn to use a debugger.

Comment: you are using sorted data right?

Comment: @denis the data in the int array is already in order, from least to greatest, it is coming from a text file.

Comment: Your code is working I tested it myself.

Comment: @denis I get this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Answer (score 0):

2 things I see you are ommiting in the source code

1. binary search will work ONLY with sorted arrays
2. this here:

```
 middle = (left + right)/2;
```

is a very dangerous overflow operation ypu have to verify

Answer (score 0):

Is this a sample of what you are looking for?

```
public class TestIndex {

    TestIndex()  {
        //Sample arrays after file load
        int[] refInts = {
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
        };
        String[] titlesArray = {
                "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer", 
                "Huckleberry Finn", 
                "The Sword in the Stone", 
                "Stuart Little", 
                "Treasure Island",
                "The Secret Garden", 
                "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland", 
                "Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea", 
                "Peter Pan", 
                "Charlotte's Web"
        };

        // Sample input captured to perform search on
        int refNumBinary = 3;

        //binary search
        int binary = binarySearch(refInts, 0, refInts.length-1, refNumBinary);

        //check binary search results
        if (binary == -1){
            System.out.println("Data not found. Please Try again.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("#" + refNumBinary + ": " + titlesArray[binary+1]);
        }
    }

    public static Integer binarySearch(int [] A, int left, int right, int V){
         int middle;
         if (left > right || right < 0) {
             return -1;
         }
         middle = (left + right)/2;
         if (V == A[middle]) {
             return middle;
         }
         if (V < A[middle]) {
             return binarySearch(A, left, middle-1, V);
         } else {
             return binarySearch(A, middle + 1, right, V);
         }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestIndex();
    }
}
```

Comment: @flip not exactly I don't think, my data comes from a text file so it can't be declared like that, see edit in original post for more info

Comment: I meant to demonstrate the search principle.  The fact whether you load your data from file or not is irrelevant as in the end you work with a data and index array.  I adjusted the sample data above to reflect this.

Comment: Can you clarify what I am missing?  I thought the question was about the search mechanism which is not properly working.  For me it seems this is working properly as the above piece of code uses the same search mechanism as your code, but in an isolated context

Comment: @flip I actually managed to fix it. You were right that the search mechanism was functioning correctly, the issue was that I had made a stupid mistake, my adding process was mixed in with the search button, thus causing it to try and add more data every time the search button was pressed, causing an error after the first search. I moved the adding process to initComponents(); and it works fine now. Thanks for your help.